# How to redirect old links to new with pattern match

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to redirect some of my old links to the new one. 
I have tried with this, but it is not working:

```
Route::redirect('/football-tipsters/{country}.html', 'standings/{country}.html', 301);
```

Do you know how to change it. I am using Laravel 5.7.6

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'd love to know if there's an official way of doing it. For now I am relying on [Laravel Missing Page Redirector](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-missing-page-redirector)

Comment: Do you have Laravel handling requests to HTML files?  Why not perform this on the  web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('standings/{country}.html', function($country){

 return response();

})->name('route.to');

Route::get('/football-tipsters/{country}.html', function ($country) {

    return redirect(route('route.to', compact('country')));

})->name('route.from');
```